# Student information system that will display a txt file

Tags: java, swing

I need help with my code. I am stuck at 2 (Search student record), we are allowed to use GUI and filehandling. Any advice and help will do. Please correct my codes if there's an error or needed to be changed.

Heres the instructions: Write a menu driven program that performs the following:

1. Save - can add N students record into the list (ID num, name, course, address)
2. Search - can search (ID num, name, course, address) - or a specific student.
3. Read - can view record by ID number, by name, by course and address - or view all

Heres my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String option = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("""
                1 = Save 
                2 = Search
                3 = Read

                Enter your choice:\s""");
        int option1 = Integer.parseInt(option);

        if (option1 == 1) {
            PrintWriter outputStream = null;
            try {
                outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Finale\\finals1.txt", true));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error cannot find location");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name: ");
            String student_id = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Student Number: ");
            String course = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Course: ");
            String address = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Address: ");

            assert outputStream != null;
            outputStream.printf(name, student_id, course, address);
            outputStream.println("");
            outputStream.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successful...");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int option3 = Integer.parseInt(option);

        if (option3 == 3) {
            try {
                FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Finale\\finals1.txt");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error cannot find location");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int option2 = Integer.parseInt(option);

            if (option2 == 2) {
                try {
                    FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Finale\\finals1.txt");
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error cannot find location");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Stacks, Jieun Lee.

Your `option2` section is embedded inside your `option3` section, so it is unreachable.

Move it to a section co-equal with option 3 and 1.

It is unnecessary to `parseInt (option)` three times. Once is enough.  The derived `int` from one can be used by all three conditional expressions.

I found this bug almost instantly when I stepped through with a debugger.  If you have one in your IDE, use it.